# how to move/rename a file within Magit?

Tags: magit

The manual's [introduction](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Introduction.html#Introduction) says:

> Magit wraps and in many cases improves upon at least the following Git porcelain commands: add, am, bisect, blame, branch, checkout, cherry, cherry-pick, clean, clone, commit, config, describe, diff, fetch, format-patch, init, log, merge, merge-tree, **mv**, notes, pull, rebase, reflog, remote, request-pull, reset, revert, rm, show, stash, submodule, and tag.

However, I can't quite figure out how to actually move a file from it. Sure I can just run `git mv`, but taking that to the logical extreme we might as well just use `git` instead of Magit :P Considering the manual mentions `mv`, I wonder if that's a mistake or not.

I only found [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610365/how-to-use-git-mv-from-magit) but it's very old by Magit standards. Perhaps things have changed?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`magit-file-rename` is bound to <kbd>R</kbd> in `magit-mode` buffers.

Comment: Please remember that the Magit status buffer uses context-sensitive keymaps! When the status buffer shows no files (as in: your working tree is clean), you have to move point to the last empty line at the bottom of this buffer and then hit `R` to execute `magit-file-rename`. If point is within a line which shows a branch (like `master`), hitting `R` will execute `magit-branch-rename` instead. Took me a while to figure this out.

Comment: The _first_ empty line will also work. Just as long as the point is not on one of the branch names near the top.

Comment: I was surprised to learn about this command because `R` doesn't show up in the `h` help menu (`magit-dispatch`).  I guess it's still necessary to use `C-h m` to list all the available bindings even with transient.